# How to use handleSubmit to submit data in form and some extra data in redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am a redux-form library newbie. I am trying to write some code to update data to server. The update API that server supports well.

I am using reactjs, redux and redux-form. 
My concise code is:

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, updatePost } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Update the Post</h4>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost.bind(this))}>
                <Field name="title" component={this.renderField} type="text" className="form-control" label="Post Title"/>
                <Field name="description" component={this.renderField} type="textarea" className="form-control" label="Post Description"/>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                <Link to='/template'>Back to List</Link>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I click on button Submit, the code `onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost.bind(this))}` will send all data in the form to my function `updatePost`. 
My question is: I want to pass some data (like an PostID). How can I do that?
I don't want to use a cheat (like hidden field in my form). 
Thank you.

Comment: OK. I agree using hidden field is not a cheat. But how can I solve my problem without using hidden field?

Comment: What is this hack `onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost.bind(this))` doing there ?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja. It's send data in form to the updatePost(data) function. I can receive all data in the form.

Comment: From where you will get the postId? What is stopping you to attach the postId to the data which is passed to server from updatePost?

Comment: Can you post your entire `component` and `parent component` too

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran. I can get my postId from Presentational and Container Components. I can send my postId from my Container but I do that from the Presentational Component.

Comment: Now, why cant you attach the postId into the data which you pass to Server?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran. I can but I need attach the postId. But I need do that in the Presentational Component instead Container. 
Like this: <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updatePost.bind(this, postId))}>

Comment: show us some more code which involves with your need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your use case is but there are a few approaches you can do...

using `setState` of parent component, you can pass it as props inside `initialValues`.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
   updatePost(formValues) {
      // process data
      this.setState({ postId: '...' });
   }
   render() {
      return <FormComponent initialValues={{postId: this.state.postId}} />
   }
}
```

Just make sure you have the `enableReinitialize` set to true when initializing your reduxForm.

`export default reduxForm({ form: 'myFormName', enableReinitialize: true })(FormComponent);`

Or

use reduxForm `change` action creator

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';

class ParentComponent extends Component {
    updatePost(formValues) {
       this.props.change('myFormName', 'postId', 'postid_value');
    }
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { change })(ParentComponent);
```

Or pass postId as props itself (`<MyForm postId={...} />`) and do the `change` action inside the MyForm component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an onChange function passed to the reduxForm decorator to submit my form after any of the form's fields change.

You can modify the form's `values` object passed to your onSubmit function in the onChange function. In the example below I'm creating new key/value pairs on the values object before it gets to my onSubmit function using the component's properties.

I haven't tested yet but this should also work for a presentational component as well.

```
//@flow
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Field, Form, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { FormLabel, FormControl, FormControlLabel } from "material-ui/Form";
import { RadioGroup } from "redux-form-material-ui";
import Radio from "material-ui/Radio";
import Paper from "material-ui/Paper";

type HccTableQuestionProps = {
  handleSubmit: Function,
  row: Object,
};

class HccTableQuestion extends PureComponent<HccTableQuestionProps> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(values) {
    console.log("hccActionForm submitted ", values);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, row } = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper style={{ padding: 9 }}>
        <Form name={"hccActionForm"} onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleChange)}>
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">HCC Action</FormLabel>
            <Field component={RadioGroup} name={"hccAction"}>
              <FormControlLabel
                value="ICD Code Submitted for CY encounter"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="ICD Code Submitted for CY encounter"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="Queried Provider"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="Queried Provider"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="Condition Not Present"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="Condition Not Present"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="No Action"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="No Action"
              />
            </Field>
          </FormControl>
        </Form>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "hccActionForm",
  enableReinitialize: true,
  onChange: (values, dispatch, props, previousValues) => {
    values.hccCode = props.hccCode; // Adding new key/value pair to values
    values.patientHccCodingId = 99999999; // Adding new key/value pair to values
    props.submit();
  },
})(HccTableQuestion);
```